# Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication, google-chrome-devtools

i created an angular app, i did gmail authentication, but it gives me a chrome error:

```
Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute
Because a cookie's SameSite attribute was not set or is invalid, it defaults to SameSite = Lax, which prevents the cookie from being sent in a cross-site request. This behavior protects user data from accidentally leaking to third parties and cross-site request forgery.
Resolve this issue by updating the attributes of the cookie:
Specify SameSite = None and Secure if the cookie should be sent in cross-site requests. This enables third-party use.
Specify SameSite = Strict or SameSite = Lax if the cookie should not be sent in cross-site requests.
```

I found a lot of solutions but too bad I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you shared that accesses Firestore. Can you make sure we can also see the minimal code for that, and how it relates to the sign-in process?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thx for you answer i edit my question